# How to change a text object in Illustrator and export programatically?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

I want to generate a bunch of pngs from an Illustrator file. They're all identical except for one specific text field which contains a number (1, 2, 3, etc.).

Is there an automatic way to generate 100 pngs that all have this text field with a different number?

Comment: You might be looking for InDesign master pages.

Comment: Yes no problem.

Comment: You can use InDesign for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You CAN do this with illustrator, using variable data. You basically have an xml file with the different texts that you then import to Illustrator to generate the graphics.

Here is a [simple tutorial](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-data-driven-graphics-using-illustrators-variables-panel--vector-5604) on how to import an xml file and use it within an illustrator document.

And here are some thoughts as to how to [convert your data into illustrator xml](http://www.monolinea.com/using-variables-illustrator/) in the first place.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thank you so much for your answer. I almost felt stupid for asking if this was even possible.

Answer (score -2):

You could use software like "Quite Imposing", which is an acrobat add-on. It can make up numbered tickets for you. The numbered tickets could have a PNG background. The software is a bit expensive but it can be worth its weight in gold considering some of the things it can do for you..